# Where to save digital content and prevent sharing?

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

Ive inspired by the answer of the question here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48047/location-to-store-an-encryption-key?newreg=68a1d15daab744dfb22801da245435f6 to store an encryption key

gave me alot to think about. Me and my friend are building a website and we've encountered a problem in which every user will have the ability to upload digital content (files) from his computer and sell them to other people.

The people who will purchase the file will have access to it(downloading it). The problem is how do I make it safely from abuse? that a user who purchased a file wont be able to share it with other people (if they will have the link they still wont be able to download the file). For example if a UserX purcahsed a file and now have the following url: www.domain.com/downloads/124asfsafsafadsa123127sdhsdc by sharing it with UserY who didnt purchased the file will raising an error message.

We are developing in php..

Comment: you cant, you never will be able to stop people sharing the files they downloaded, welcome to the internet

Comment: Require a login from the purchaser, and limit the time that the link is available.

Comment: You'd have to modify the files themselves to add some sort of DRM protection to them.

Comment: @Zarathuztra do you know any DRM protection that actully 'works' ?

Comment: Works? Nah, but it's really the only option here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking to the file directly, put the file outside your webroot and
serve it via php after you've verified that the user has permission to access the file.

This will prevent unauthorized downloads from your server (which is useful if you're trying to save bandwidth) but it obviously doesn't prevent someone from sharing the file after they've downloaded it.

```
if(userHasPermissionToDownload($_GET['some_file_id'])) {
    $local_path = getLocalPath($_GET['some_file_id']);
    header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($local_path));
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_path));
    readfile($local_path);  
    exit;
}
else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Most sites use some kind of token i'm wondering how they are building these tokens for specific buyer.

Comment: And in what way should i store the links and the file paths in my database? as it is (plain text)? or encrypted in some way(cipher text)?